# this ajax call is not calling , what is missing in my code, any one can explain

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
var userId = window.localStorage.getItem("zicuserId");
var dataString = "deviceId="+myDeviceId + "&userId=" + userId + "&deviceToken=" + myDeviceToken;
alert("dataString: " + dataString);
$.ajax({
        type: POST,
        url: "http://mobilapps.zicoil.pk/fineName.php",
        data: dataString,
        async: false,
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data)
        {
            window.localStorage.setItem("userDeviceRegister", "true");
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function()
        {
            alert("error , you are in error function.")
        }
    });
```

Comment: `POST` -> `"POST"`?

Comment: Might be CORS. Anyhow, please post the console HTTP error you're getting, so we can help

Comment: + Missing function name in `url`

Comment: [Open the browser's console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) and don't use `alert` for debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have syntax error in this line: `type: POST,`. Just replace `POST` to `"POST"`. This param should be string, now it is notdefined variable.

BTW: You should use browser console to detect this kind of errors.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```js
var userId = window.localStorage.getItem("zicuserId");
var dataString = {deviceId:myDeviceId,userId:userId,deviceToken:myDeviceToken};
alert("dataString: " + dataString);
$.ajax({
        url: "http://mobilapps.zicoil.pk/fineName.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: dataString,
        async: false,
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data)
        {
            window.localStorage.setItem("userDeviceRegister", "true");
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function()
        {
            alert("error , you are in error function.")
        }
    });
```